# Version control with Certification authentication

Tags: svn, version-control, certificate, visualsvn-server

I am trying to create a eclipse like IDE which serves different purpose. In my IDE, I am using VisualSVN for check-in and check-out of the projects.

The problem with VisualSVN is, the authentication is done through username and password alone. I also want to increase the security by using digital certificates.

I want to know which windows version control server have an option of sending certificates also. Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: I believe SVN also asks to accept certificate when trying to connect to a repository for the first time?

Comment: No.. It doesn't have an option to check for certificates.

Comment: Did you read this: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/